# Rotating by 90° one and more polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector-layer, rotate

I have a layer with many rectangles polygons, these should all be rotated by 90°. Can I do this in QGIS? I have not found a way so far.

Answer (score 5):

Try the ["Rotate"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#rotate) tool.

> Rotates feature geometries by the specified angle clockwise. The
> rotation occurs around each feature’s centroid, or optionally around a
> unique preset point.

Also possible by means of the ["Affine transform"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#affine-transform) geoalgorithm.

> Applies an affine transformation to the layer geometries. Affine
> transformations can include translation, scaling and rotation. The
> operations are performed in the following order: scale, rotation, and
> translation.